# Rails 3.1 No route matches controller and action but they exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm playing with a test rails app. However I stumbled on a problem I can't resolve.
I've a users controller and in it there's an activate method.

In the routes.rb file I have

```
match 'activate/:email/:validation_code' => 'users#activate', :as => :activate_user, :via => :get
```

After that I try to use `activate_user_path(@user)` but a routing error is raised.

`No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"activate", :email=>#<User id: 12, email: "someone@test.test", validation_code: "zbBPLQUsBgPvEJfcjxmXuxFxuJAKEoqQNASkbybihpnmzSbhxdC...", active: false, created_at: "2011-11-10 14:56:23", updated_at: "2011-11-10 14:56:23">}`

Running `rake routes` shows the routing is there:

`activate_user GET  /activate/:email/:validation_code(.:format) {:controller=>"users", :action=>"activate"}`

I tried searching for this problem, but usually this happens when you forget to pass the object that's needed to build the route.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post the full error message instead of trailing off with `...` right where it gets important?

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't think it was important. The remaining part contained the other fields of the user object. I will edit the post now to include them.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you are actually invoking a GET and not a POST as the method.

If you are submitting a form, it defaults to POST, which would mean you don't have a matching route, the route you listed above only works for GET requests.

Comment: Actually this happens when using the `activate_user_path(@user)` to build a link in a view, so no invoking of requests there. If I manually type the URL in the browser address field the same happens - no route matches.

Answer (score 0):

Does activate_user_path(:email => @user.email, :validataion_code => @user.validation_code) works for you?

EDIT

I don't know why, but when I've changed:
validation_code to code it works.

```
match 'activate/:email/:code' => 'users#activate', :as => :activate_user, :via => :get
```

Probably in rails you can't use var names in routes with underscore, but this has to be verified.

Comment: I've tried this too before posting to SO. The result is the same. The only difference is of course the dump of the error, where it doesn't list the whole object but only these two passed properties.

Comment: Okay, so this is weird, cause I've tried this in my routes, and tested in rails console, and it works for me. So please double check this. You can use app.activate_user_path(:email => "foo", :code =>"bar") in rails console

Comment: I'm feeling I'm doing something totally wrong. In the rails console no error is returned. The correct path is shown - `=> "/activate/foo/bar"`. However when I launch rails s the error is still there.
Does it matter that I'm using the _path or _url method in ActionMailer template?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Did you restart server, before testing it ? I think you can also try another approach to accomplish user activation. Use only validatoincode in the path, and then in the user#activate action: user = User.find_by_validation_code... You don't need email, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was something stupid of me. You can't put an email in the URI. :) Currently with all the revisions it works if the first parameter doesn't contain a @ symbol.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4887/discussion-between-zbrox-and-sparrovv)